# Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\#'

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, itext

I am reading a text file and trying to parse it as an html and make a pdf of it with `iTextSharp`.

Here I load the text file:

```
string HTML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Misc/Html.txt"));
HTML = HTML.Replace("[Date]", Paristan.Broker.UI.Components.PersianDate.GetDate(DateTime.Now));
HTML = HTML.Replace("[Title]", person.Title);
HTML = HTML.Replace("[Person]", person.Name);
```

The `HTML.txt` contains something like the following:

```
<body id='prt-body'><div class='prt-container'><header id='prt-header'><div id='prt-header-logo'><img src='#'></div><ul id='prt-header-information'><li><span>تاریخ: </span><label>[Date]</label>...
```

And here I try to parse it as html and print it in a pdf:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Pdf/test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
try
{
    List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTML), null);
    for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
    {
        document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
    }

    document.Close();
}
catch
{
    document.Close();
}
```

And I tried this too:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Pdf/test.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
try
{
    iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
    hw.StartDocument();
    hw.Parse(new StringReader(HTML));
    hw.EndDocument();
    hw.Close();
    document.Close();
}
catch
{
    document.Close();
}
```

The pdf file is created but its empty. I see the following error in line 6 in the first code and in line 8 in the second code. The error is:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express#'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be parsing the `<img src='#'>` part of your HTML, and subsequently attempting to load the image. Try using a real image path, or removing the `img` tag.

Comment: Great. I will accept your answer after 5 minutes..Thanks.;)